# How many students do not wear glasses and do not bring lunch?

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math

**Question :**

> In a school there are $500$ students. Two-thirds of the students who do not wear glasses, do not bring lunch. Three-quarters of the students who do not bring lunch do not wear glasses. Altogether, $60$ students who wear glasses bring lunch. How many students do not wear glasses and do not bring lunch?

This is what tried:

I let the
Number of students who don't wear glass =$$x$$
Number of students who don't bring lunch =$$y$$
Number of students who neither wear glass nor bring lunch=$$z$$

$$500-(x+y+z) = 60$$
$$x+y+z= 440$$
$$\frac{3z}{2} + \frac{4z}{3} + z = 440$$
$$z=\frac{2640}{23}$$

I think my equation is wrong.
I don't want the whole solution. Just tell me the equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide the children into four parts :

- $a$ : those who don't wear glasses, and don't bring lunch.
- $b$ : Those who wear glasses but don't bring lunch.
- $c$ : those who bring lunch but don't wear glasses.
- $d$ : Those who do both (fun fact : I was in this category in school)

---

- "In a school there are 500 students" : $a+b+c+d = 500$.
- "Two-thirds of the students who do not wear glasses, do not bring lunch" : Those who don't wear glasses is $a+c$. Of this, $a$ is two-thirds, so $a = \frac 23(a+c)$.
- " Three-quarters of the students who do not bring lunch do not wear glasses" - $a+b$ is all those who don't bring lunch, and $a$ is three-quarters of this i.e. $a = \frac 34(a+b)$.
- "Altogether, 60 students who wear glasses bring lunch" - $d = 60$.

You have to find $a$.

---

Completing this question.

From $a = \frac 34(a+b)$, we get $a = \frac 34a + \frac 34b$ so that $4a = 3a+3b$ and $a = 3b$.

From $a = \frac 23(a+c)$, we get $a = 2c$.

We know that $a+b+c = 500-d = 500-60 = 440$. Let's write $k = \frac a6$. Then, $a = 6k, b = 2k$ and $b = 3k$.

Therefore, $a+b+c = 11k = 440$, and thus $ k =\frac{440}{11} = 40$. Finally, $a = 240,b= 80,c=120$.

We were looking for $a$ , so the answer is $$
\boxed{240}
$$

Comment: How did you write so much in 2 minutes? Writing Question took my 30 minutes.

Comment: @Mayank This is your second question on the site, but my 1800th post or so. It comes with practice, and I am sure your next question will be written even better than this one (which is also very nice!)